# Sails.js - Authorisation issues with remote MongoDB on mLab but working fine locally

Tags: mongodb, heroku, sails.js

Recently, I took over a Sails.js application created for our company by a small team of web developers. They provided me with the source and a database dump. Now, my task is to get it up and running on Heroku. While everything is working okay when I run the app locally, with the remote connection there is an error on startup that says:

```
MongoError: not authorized on heroku_gbntc8sf to execute command { createIndexes: "agendaJobs", indexes: [ { key: { name: 1, priority: -1, lockedAt: 1, nextRunAt: 1, disabled: 1 }, name: "findAndLockNextJobIndex1" }, { key: { name: 1, lockedAt: 1, priority: -1, nextRunAt: 1, disabled: 1 }, name: "findAndLockNextJobIndex2" } ] }
  at Function.MongoError.create ([ROOT_DIR]/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
  at [ROOT_DIR]/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:793:66
  at Callbacks.emit ([ROOT_DIR]/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:94:3)
  at null.messageHandler ([ROOT_DIR]/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:235:23)
  at Socket.<anonymous> ([ROOT_DIR]/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:259:22)
  at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
  at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
  at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
  at TCP.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

Here's a quick checklist of what I've done already:

- checked the build log on Heroku - no errors or warnings;
- set up mLab Heroku add-on, exported the database, done some manual checks from the mLab dashboard - everything looks okay;
- logged in to the database remotely from the `mongo` command and a `mongo://` URL, ran a few simple queries, and obtained information on the database user privileges;
- created an identical user (with the `heroku_gbntc8sf` username, same password, same role, etc.) in the local database.

Here's what the connection configuration looks like:

```
// config/connections.js    
module.exports.connections = {
  mongodb: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    user: 'heroku_gbntc8sf',
    password: [HIDDEN],
    host: 'ds159387.mlab.com',
    port: 59387,
    database: 'heroku_gbntc8sf'
  },

  // ...
}

// config/env/development.js
module.exports = {
  models: {
    connection: 'mongodb'
  },

  // ...
}

// config/env/production.js
module.exports = {
  models: {
    connection: 'mongodb'
  },

  // ...
}
```

At the moment I'm running the server locally, trying to connect to the remote database, to eliminate as many variables as possible. Like I mentioned above, when I set `host` to `'127.0.0.1'` and `port` to `27017`, everything works okay. The `heroku_gbntc8sf` user has basic `readWrite` permissions in both databases (local and remote). In fact, those two databases are pretty much identical, as far as I know. And yet...

I've read a sizeable chunk of the Sails.js documentation, as well as, the documentation on the `sails-mongo` adapter. I've searched for similar questions, but I couldn't find anything relevant. I've tried many different things, including a couple of different ways to configure the database connection, but that error is always there.

The reason why I'm posting to StackOverflow is that I cannot rely on the support from the original authors of the app at the moment. Also, I'm new to Sails.js, so I might be doing something wrong without even knowing. I was hoping that I could get away with treating the app as a 'black box' (or like a generic Node application), since my job is only to start the app on Heroku.

Answer (score 3):

I've successfully used mLab in a Sails project recently, but I've used the Mongo URL string format, for example...

```
mongodbServer: {
        adapter: 'sails-mongo',
        url    : "mongodb://dandanknight:som3P455w0rd@ds044979.mlab.com:44979/databasename"
    }
```

Not sure if it helps, but can't hurt to try! It's also the only way I've successfully got a replicaSet working in Sails incidentally.

It's confusing, but I read the sails-mongo docs as "URL is the way forward, and passing an object is legacy usage" ([here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo))